# Coloration of orthophoto different between QGIS and ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, color, orthophoto, agisoft-photoscan

I have an orthophoto created with Agisoft Photoscan that I would like to use for a map.

Why is there a difference in coloration between QGIS and ArcGIS?

For the record, the color showing in QGIS is identical to how it looks in Photoscan, whereas in ArcGIS it appears too red.

[image]

Comment: Check if ArcGIS applies automatic contrast enhancement.

Answer (score 4):

After looking through the layer properties in ArcGIS, I noticed under the Symbology tab that a "percent clip" stretch was applied by default for some reason... I changed it to none, and it looks like it should.

Seems very odd to me this was a default setting.

Comment: It makes most images, even those with poor contrast, to look bright for bare eyes.